# Apache Flume multiple agent

Tags: flume

I have tested Apache Flume to transfer files from local to HDFS. But if the source files from multiple servers (transfer files from different servers' local to HDFS), can I just run one Flume instance and just add more agents into flume-conf.properties?

If I can, how can I edit the following parameters in flume-conf.properties:

```
agent1.sources.spooldirSource1.spoolDir = ?(server1/path)
agent2.sources.spooldirSource2.spoolDir = ?(server2/path)
```

And also, how can I run flume?

```
./flume-ng agent -n agent -c conf -f apache-flume-1.4.0-bin/conf/flume-conf.properties
```

can only run one flume. What about more than two?

Answer (score 3):

Add multiple sources for what you need but configure them to use the same channel - which will then use the same source. So it's something like (note that this snippet is incomplete):

```
agent1.sources.spooldirSource1.spooldir = server1/path
agent1.sources.spooldirSource1.channel = myMemoryChannel
agent1.sources.spooldirSource2.spooldir = server2/path
agent1.sources.spooldirSource2.channel = myMemoryChannel
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the same channel for two source isn't the good pratice , you can easly get outOfMemory for the channel (for MemoryChannel) and in this case.
it's better to use a channel for every source (for the same agent)

```
a1.sources = r1 r2
a1.sinks = k1 k2
a1.channels = c1 c2
```

then link source r1 to the channel c1 and source r2 to channel c2